# formatting SQLPlus terminal output (very long data_type column width)

Tags: terminal, output, sqlplus, truncate

I have a script 
check_table.sql:

```
set verify off
set trimout off
rem set wrap off
set linesize 200

select table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length from dba_tab_columns where table_name IN '&1' and owner in 'SOMEUSER';
quit;
```

The output width is very long:

```
TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_TYPE                                                                                          DATA_LENGTH
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
ABCPROC                        PROC_ID                        NUMBER                                                                                                      22
ABCPROC                        PROC_NAME                      VARCHAR2                                                                                                   200
ABCPROC                        PROC_USER                      NUMBER                                                                                                      22
```

How can I make the DATA_TYPE column to be trucated without truncating the whole row in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just format the output e.g.

COL DATA_TYPE FORMAT A10

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a82950/ch4.htm